# Ubuntu 18.04 Xampp Desktop Icon gives error dialogue - There was an error launching the application

Tags: xampp

I am having trouble getting a desktop icon for Xampp to work.  Here is my .desktop code:-

```
[[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

However if I run :-

pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run

in terminal it works fine.  I have set permissions to execute file as a program and chmod 777.  As a small point, only a default icon shows not the Xampp icon

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK Sorted it - code below solves problem :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start or Stop XAMPP
Exec=sh -c "pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run"
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Name[en_US]=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment[en_US]=Start or Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

Still have small problem, when Xampp opens an icon appears in the vertical favourites bar on the left, but instead of the Xampp icon it displays a standard 'package' icon (a red circle with a red diagonal, like a no entry sign).  I will post as a separate question but keep researching and experimenting myself.